# How to addition one to string in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have value from varchar like this 'M000000000009', and I expect result of this value incremented by 1, 'M000000000010'.
How can i do this?

```
select 'M000000000009'+ 1 from dual
```

Comment: The simplest way is to fix your table schema, so you have a *prefix* column and a *number* column. Plus you need to fix the query that outputs your frankenvalue to *format* these two values together in the correct way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try this select:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('M000000000009', 1, 1) || LPAD((TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('M000000000009',2)) + 1), 12, '0') NEW_SERIAL
FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 1):

Any time we find ourselves asking a question such as "how do I add 1 to a string?" we know we've made a design error. It's like asking "which of these ties goes better with this polo neck?" It's just wrong.

`'M000000000009'` is what is known as a "smart key". That is, one column which actually comprises two or more parts. This is breaks first normal form because it's not atomic (although atomicity is [tricky to define](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Atomicity)).

But this is not some abstract design point: smart keys are dumb. They are hard to work with, as you have discovered. Inevitably we find ourselves wielding SUBSTR and INSTR when writing queries or populating records.

The better implementation is to store the atomic components of the smart key as separate columns and concatenate them when presenting them to the user. This was still a bit of a pain but Oracle removed the pfaffing about in 11g with the introduction of the highly neat virtual column. These are rule-based columns which are populated automatically from other columns. We can build indexes and even constraints on virtual columns.

So in your example you have a key which comprises an alphabetical prefix and a monotonically increasing number. You can implement it like this:

```
create table t23 
  ( cat_code varchar2(1) not null 
    , cat_number number(11,0) not null 
    , catalogue_no varchar2(12) 
        as (cast(cat_code||lpad(to_char(cat_number), 11, '0') as varchar2(12))) virtual 
    , constraint t23_pk primary key (catalogue_no) 
 )
```

[LiveSQL demo script.](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/fty4x6qgbx6lgmgwbh1be4x3t)

The numeric component `cat_number` is a number so you can populate it as any other number - by arithmetic, with a sequence or - since 12c - as an IDENTITY column:

```
create table t23
  ( cat_code varchar2(1) not null
    , cat_number number generated always as identity
    , catalogue_no varchar2(12) as (cast(cat_code||lpad(to_char(cat_number), 11, '0') as varchar2(12))) virtual
    , constraint t23_pk primary key (catalogue_no)
 )
/
```

Answer (score 0):

brute force and not pretty

```
select
       substr(str,1,1) || substr(concat('0000000000000' , cast(substr(str,2,13) as int) + 1),-12) x
  from (
    select
       'M000000000009' as str
    from dual
     )
```

nb: will fail if the second to last part of that string does not cast to an integer