# Oracle sql how to restrict the length of letters/numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to restrict the container id to be letter "E" on a front and then up to 7 digits, ex.: `E1234567`.

How can I do that in Oracle sql?

The simplest example: `select * from inventory where container_id like ???`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to addition one to string in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47233329/how-to-addition-one-to-string-in-oracle)

Comment: Aside from regexes, you can check length using the `length` function.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to restrict"? Only in a query (in the WHERE clause), or in the table itself - no container ID should ever allowed to be saved in the table unless it has that specific format?

Comment: This is poor design. `Container_id` should be two columns, say `container_prefix varchar2(1)` and `container_no number(7,0)`. See this SO thread for more discussion of [so-called "smart" keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47236263/146325)

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to modify your query, this would suggest using `REGEXP_LIKE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM inventory
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (container_id, '^E[0-9]{1,7}$');
```

If on the other hand you are looking for a way to enforce your pattern for every container ID, then you can try adding a check constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE inventory
ADD CONSTRAINT check_inv
CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE (container_id, '^E[0-9]{1,7}$'));
```

Comment: @Joanna Your above comment has zero relationship to the question you asked.  If the comment is the real issue, you might want to ask a new question.

Comment: @Rose - What is Red Prairie? What relationship is there between it and Oracle? There is no mention of Red Prairie in your original question.

Comment: @mathguy The surface of Mars could be described as a red prairie, if it had a few plants and animals living there :-)

Comment: I guess the OP works at one of JDA's [global centres of excellence](http://now.jda.com/RedPrairie-Now-JDA.html)